# tf2_ros::Buffer.transform() missing timestamp

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, tf2-ros, buffer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone
I use `tf2_ros::Buffer.transform()` to transform a `geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped` into a`geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped` in another frame at the same time. So the syntax is:

```
tf2_ros::Buffer.transform(geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped wrenchStamped1, geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped wrenchStamped2, const std::string & target_frame, ros::Duration timDur);
```

It seems to work fine but the wrenchStamped2 has an empty timestamp. Is this on purpose by the function and do I need to manually assign the timestamp?

The code looks basically like this (msg is the message from the subscriber callback function this code snippet is part of):

```
 geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped msgWrench = msg->wrench;
 msgWrench.header = msg->header;
 msgWrench.header.frame_id = "EE_FORCETORQUESENSOR";

 geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped worldFrameWrenchFTSensorStamped;
  try 
  {
    ros::Duration timDur(0.1);
    std::string target_frame_("world");
    buffer_.transform(msgWrench, worldFrameWrenchFTSensorStamped, target_frame_, timDur);
  }
  catch (tf2::TransformException &ex) 
  {
    ROS_WARN("Failure %s\n", ex.what()); //Print exception which was caught
  }

  worldFrameWrenchFTSensorStamped.header = msgWrench.header;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361539/tf2_ros::buffer.transform()-missing-timestamp/) by [dimitri](https://answers.ros.org/users/53755/dimitri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2020-09-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-09-15**:
Can you provide the actual code in which you're using your `tf2_ros::Buffer` object? Just the surrounding function or a few lines above and below would help.

**Comment by [dimitri](https://answers.ros.org/users/53755/dimitri/) on 2020-09-24**:
Sorry. I added the code. I hope it is clear what i am doing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`tf2_ros::Buffer.transform()` is a [templated function](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/fe0457fe0d761a1dcc9182f9cc09912b3a4a8e2d/tf2_ros/include/tf2_ros/buffer_interface.h#L127) that calls `tf2::doTransform(in, out, lookupTransform(target_frame, tf2::getFrameId(in), tf2::getTimestamp(in), timeout));` under the hood. The `lookupTransform()` part is the one we care about here, because it is the one that generates a `geometry_msgs::TransformStamped` with a timestamp that gets passed to `doTransform`. Through a few redirections, this eventually ends up with a call to `BufferCore::doTransform()` [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/dae26a225e6c14a5aabd25a8b08c3031e6563535/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp#L594). Looking at that function doesn't help a ton because it requires knowledge of how the TF frame cache works, but, essentially, if both the input WrenchStamped and the TF that gets published between the two frames have valid timestamps, the output WrenchStamped should have a valid timestamp too. Verify this on both of those messages - I'm guessing this will point to the source of your problem.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dimitri](https://answers.ros.org/users/53755/dimitri/) on 2020-09-25**:
Thanks. You were right. The problem was not with the code but with the data in the messages I was using.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at your code, you're continuing even if the exception happens. You should not continue processing after you catch the exception. That's an exception and will not have changed the worldFrameWrenchFTSensorStamped data values, which will consequently be zero as you're describing. Which is the most likely reason for a zero time stamp as you describe.

Please see the [tf2 tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials) to make sure that you're catching the exceptions properly, as well as potentially [using a MessageFilter](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Using%20stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf2%3A%3AMessageFilter) to hold data until the transform is available.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-09-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dimitri](https://answers.ros.org/users/53755/dimitri/) on 2020-09-25**:
Thanks for pointing that out. It wasn't the reason for the problem but it was obviously wrong to not return after the exception was thrown.